# IF Statement on Range Of Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a range of cells that I would like to look at with this if statement.  I basically want this formula to look at the "Customer" and then look at a list of Customers that provide their own routing, if that "Customer" is on that list (in that range of cells) then i would need for the formula to return a "Y" for yes and if they are not on that list then i just need an "N" for no.  I've included a picture.  Then range of cells that it needs to look at is G10:G28.[image: example]

Comment: You need to do a VLOOKUP if you want to get a range of cells.  You can use that to grab and displa whatever data you need based on that range.

Comment: I don't think a VLOOKUP alone will work because what do I point to when it asked for the Col Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VLOOKUP can tell if an item is in the first column of a specified set of cells.  You could wrap it in an if in order to give you the Y/N value

The basic syntax would be like this.

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(F2, $G$10:$G$28, 1, false)), "N", "Y")

Additionally, if you had a specific value that you wanted to display when a match was found, you could have that value in column H and use a slightly different formula.  You'll want to further investigate the VLOOKUP function if you are not familiar with how it works.
Something like 
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F2, $G$10:$H$28, 2, false), "N")

Comment: It brought back all no's with this formula.  How should I proceed?

Comment: If you are using the first formula you should check that the ranges are correct.  The N outcome will show when the VLOOKUP function returns #N/A, which means it did not find a matching value.  VLOOKUP expects the text value to match exactly, so if you have trailing spaces or anything like that you may need to modify the text.

Comment: They both return N.  I checked that all data was exact.  When I paste your formula and look inside the FX it shows an error

Comment: If VLOOKUP returns #N/A that means the value it is searching for was not found.  I guessed at the locations based on what you provided, so you may need to modify them.  This may help, the parameters for the formula are like this VLOOKUP([The value I am searching for], [The range I am searching In], [Column Index you want to return from your range, just use 1], [Range Lookup (I used FALSE here because I assumed you were expecting an exact match)])  If any of those don't match what you are expecting then you'll need to adjust.

Comment: Ok.  I made sure the location range it was looking it was correct.  Also validated the data it should find is there.  Don't know why it would still return NA. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: If you are still getting #N/A for a value that you know should be found then I would suggest reading the Microsoft help for VLOOKUP. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Comment: Sorry about that.  It is correct.  It is in G10:G28, but on a different sheet.  All I had to do was modify that and it worked.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: Oh gotcha that one gets us all.  I would make sure to put a $ before the row and column for that range.  That will make it a static range and when you copy or fill the formula it will always stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

You could use COUNTIF like this

=IF(COUNTIF(G$10:G$28,F2),"Y","N")